# paypalobjects checkout button not visible in dynamically loaded view

Tags: javascript, razor, paypal

If I place the following code in the main page, it works fine and displays a Paypal checkout button which also works fine.

```
<div class="rel">
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/button.js?"
            data-merchant="braintree"
            data-id="paypal-button"
            data-button="checkout"
            data-color="gold"
            data-size="medium"
            data-shape="pill"
            data-button_type="button"
            data-button_disabled="false">

    </script>
</div>
```

The problems arises when I update the div on a button click and loads the SCRIPT tag dynamically. The Paypal checkout button does not appear then. Is there a way to make the same button work without switching to the latest official Paypal Checkout API?

There is a button on the main page. I dynamically load the child DIV on that button click, using the below code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnPaypal').click(function () {
            $.ajax({ url: "@Url.Action("PaypalContent", "NewPaymentMethod")" }).done(function (data) {
                $("#divPaypal").show();
                $("#divPaypalContent").html(data);    

            });
        })
     });
</script>
```

And `data` contains inner DIV html and button script as I have shared in the start of the question.

**UPDATE:**
There are no console errors and the final page source displays only the empty container DIV, as below:

```
<div class="rel">
</div>
```

Comment: How do you dynamically change div? please include code.

Comment: @Justcode I have updated the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Please inspect what you are getting in data and check console if there is any error, add data to your question too.

Comment: @Justcode I have updated the question again. There are no console errors and I am getting the `DIV` code in the `data` (the 1st code snippet in my question).

Comment: that is the problem if you are getting empty container how you are expecting it to be a paypal button if you don't have it in source.

Comment: @Justcode That is what I asked in my question. Where did the script go in dynamic loading, although it is part of the AJAX response? It works fine in one time FULL loading.

Comment: Please check console and see what you are getting from the api call.

Comment: Use `append()` instead of `html()`, so your code will be `$("#divPaypalContent").html('').append(data);`

Comment: The code needs to be initiated in the RESPONSE function of the ajax request.

Comment: @Shifrin I doubt that it is gona create any difference as the container DIV is empty in the start.

Comment: I couldn't understand what are you trying to say however I have found some links I hope it will help you.
[https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout), [https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/button-manager/](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/button-manager/)